# Installing NVS Vector Stream Tool with ArcGIS Desktop version later than 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox, stream-order

I can't seem to get a response form NVS about their [Vector Stream Tool](http://store.nvisionsolutions.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=3) add-on, but they did send me a fixed-up version that I have now been able to install.

However, I cannot find any associated toolbox.

I have tried System Toolbox, My Toolbox, looking in the installation directory, and searching in my default geodatabase, but I can't find a way to add this tool (or toolbox) to my GIS.

Has anyone else been able to successfully install the Vector Stream Tool into ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 for Desktop (ArcMap), and might anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I have installed the Vector Stream Tool with ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 SP1. I am also not able to see any toolboxes, in the installation folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\NVision Solutions\VectorTools); it is only help files and a bunch of .dll files.

Registering GPVectorTools.dll (I suspect this one is responsible for the logic) with the esriregasm (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin) works fine yet I am not able to add any .dll from the Customize menu (getting the "can't load type library from specified file" error). Usually these things are solved by adding .tlb files (are created when compiling a solution in Visual Studio) instead of .dll when registering from the Customize menu yet there are none.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the procedure from http://www.nvisionsolutions.com/products/documentation/NVS_VectorStreamTool_Installation.pdf.

It is not very intuitive because there is no .tbx file, rather you have to create an empty toolbox, right click it, and select add > tool, and there you will find the vector tools.

I have not tested this using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: the link you provided is not working. Do you have updated link by the chance?

Comment: I'ts been quite a while since I wrote this comment and I havent used arcGIS in several years, but I think the text I wrote bellow the link is the description of what you should do? Does that work? (creating the empty toolbox and adding the tools)

Comment: I have not tried that yet because I am not sure if it will work without elevation data but study area was smaller than I thought so I did it manually.  Thank you anyway!