# NVS Vector Stream Order Tool gives 000816 Tool is Not Valid in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.2, vector, error-000816

I am trying to use the NVS vector stream order tool (designed for ArcGIS 10.0) in ArcGIS 10.2. The tool is [available for free](http://store.nvisionsolutions.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=3).

Whenever I attempt to operate the tool I am met with the error message:

> [000816 Tool is Not Valid](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000013000816)

I am assuming that this is due to the tools incompatibility with ArcGIS 10.2.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22735/how-to-calculate-stream-order-for-vector-data-without-a-dem/112999#112999) page on GIS SE, you should consider the limitations of this tool.

Comment: Although your question relates to 10.2 when the Q&A at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49534/is-it-possible-to-install-nvs-vector-stream-tool-with-arcgis-10-1-sp1 involves 10.1 and 10.1 SP1, I think it represents a duplicate i.e. "how to use NVS with later than ArcGIS 10.0".  I think you should email the tool developer i.e. info@nvisionsolutions.com (from http://www.nvisionsolutions.com/).